# MPAndroidChart - How to set x axis labels independent of chart data

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Using `MPAndroidCharts`, imagine I have the following entries:

```
{x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 4, y: 4} and {x: 6, y: 10}
```

And I wanna show the following labels on the x axis:

```
{x: 1, label: "A"}, {x: 4, label: "B"}, {x: 7, label: "C"} and {x: 10, label: "D"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [valueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) to change the Axis labels to what you want

```java
XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
        // Make sure we get the values in the right places
        xl.setAxisMaximum(10f);
        xl.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xl.setGranularity(1f);
        xl.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        // Create a formatter that returns the right string for each value
        xl.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter()
        {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                String str="";
                if(value==1f)
                    str="A";
                else if(value==4f)
                    str="B";
                else if(value==7f)
                    str="C";
                else if(value==10f)
                    str="D";
                else
                    str="";
                return str;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately using max, min and granularity doesn't work perfect and I still get labels where I don't want them

Comment: max, min and granularity just set the labels at the right interval of "1", it is the `ValueFormatter` determines if there is a label to show or not. If you have a label where you don't want it then `getFormattedValue` is not returning an empty label at the right value. As your question is a vague abstract question it's difficult to see what you have done wrong or this might not work with your chart type. Show real code example and you might get a better answer.